# Массив разных типов

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++, типы-данных

Как можно через шаблоны создать массив из разных типов(double, char, int и тд)?

Comment: Массив по определению содержит элементы одного типа. Если нужно несколько элементов разных типов, то это называется кортеж (`tuple`).

Comment: Вам стоит рассказать о том, чего вы хотите эти добиться этим, какую задачу решить.

Comment: А чем вам не нравится массив вариантов `VARIANT array[];`?

Comment: В самом задании нужно создать массив из типов char и double для его последующей сортировки

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, я добавил к нему сортировку.

Comment: Так что, вы получили ответ на ваш вопрос или нет? Или переформулируйте, или поставьте зелёную галочку. Вопрос всёещё считается не отвеченым. Как вариант - напишите как вы решили проблему.

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать `std::tuple` вместо массива. Придется немного еще потрудиться, чтобы создать итератор для такого хранилища.
2. Использовать старинный union. Non-type-safe. Можно придать юниону тег:

`struct Element { enum { D, C, I } type; union { double d; char c; int i; } data; };`

и получить run-time type resolution, и сделать C++ немного более динамическим языком.

3. Можно обобщить 2. и сделать какой-нибудь совсем обобщенный boxed type. Ну или использовать `std::variant`. Или свой простенький variant: три поля разных типов, три конструктора с аргументами разных типов, три оператора приведения к разным типам, тег конкретного типа.

Вариантов тьма, не сочтите за каламбур.

Comment: tuple здесь причем?

Comment: Коллекция значений разных типов? Действительно!

Comment: union одновременно хранит одно значение, variant - тоже, а tuple - все сразу, поэтому вариант 1 отличается от 2 и 3 принципиально в другую сторону.

Comment: Его можно рассматривать как underlying storage для класса, который обеспечивает все стандартные методы массива. Сам класс при этом даже создавать не обязательно, обойтись библиотекой функций доступа, итерации и т. п.

Comment: Если вы не поняли, речь о том, чтобы использовать std::tuple, а не массив, как хранилище. Если количество и типы элементов известны в компайл-тайме.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду использовать сам tuple как гетерогенный контейнер? Я почему-то подумал, что предлагаете tuple использовать как элемент контейнера.

Comment: Да, именно это. :)

Answer (score -1):

Один из вариантов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

union my_type
{
    double d;
    char sym;
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<my_type> mas;
    my_type x;
    x.d = 1.1;
    mas.push_back(x);
    x.sym = 's';
    mas.push_back(x);
    x.num = -2;
    mas.push_back(x);
    std::cout << "{" << mas[0].d << "," << mas[1].sym << "," << mas[2].num << "}" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Но в этом случае вам придётся самому помнить, в какой индекс вектора какой реально тип вы положили.

Можно также создать `std::vector<void*>` , но за тем, какой тип вы положите туда, придётся следить самостоятельно (плюс в этом случае контроль за очисткой памяти ложится на вас).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class someType {
public:
    someType() = default;
    ~someType() = default;
    virtual void print(ostream&) {}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, someType *&value);
    virtual double getData() {};
};

ostream& operator << (ostream &os, someType *&value){
    value->print(os);
    return os;
}

class doubleType : public someType {
private:
    double data;
public:
    doubleType(double data) : someType() {
        this->data = data;
    }
    void print(ostream& os){
        os << data;
    }
    double getData(){
        return data;
    }
};


class intType : public someType {
private:
    int data;
public:
    intType(int data) : someType() {
        this->data = data;
    }
    void print(ostream& os){
        os << data;
    }
    double getData(){
        return data;
    }
};

class charType : public someType {
private:
    char data;
public:
    charType(char data) : someType() {
        this->data = data;
    }
    void print(ostream& os){
        os << data;
    }
    double getData(){
        return data;
    }
};



int main(){
    vector<someType*> el;
    el.push_back(new charType('z'));
    el.push_back(new intType(10));
    el.push_back(new doubleType(10.01));
    el.push_back(new charType('c'));


    for_each(el.begin(), el.end(), [](someType* value) -> void {
        cout << value << endl;
    });

    sort(el.begin(), el.end(), [] (someType* first, someType* second) -> bool {
        return first->getData() < second->getData();
    });

    for_each(el.begin(), el.end(), [](someType* value) -> void {
        cout << value << endl;
    });
}
```

https://ideone.com/uTcl2V

stdout:

```
До сортировки
z
10
10.01
c

После
10
10.01
c
z
```

Сортировка с преобразованием к double. (К комментарию в вопросе)
 Свой способ сортировки вы можете задать в лямбда функции указанной в функции sort().

- Базовый класс: someType
- Его наследники: doubleType, intType

Самый обычный полиморфизм:

1. создаете любой контейнер или просто массив
2. тип контейнера должен быть указателем на базовый класс
3. далее просто выделяете память под нужного вам наследника

Каждый наследник имеет поле с соответствующим ему типом данных.

Answer (score -1):

Что-то вроде этого должно работать, не проверял _(ツ)_/

```
//Variable.h
#ifndef VARIABLE_H
#define VARIABLE_H


class Variable{
    string type;
    void* value;
public:
    template<typename Type>
    Variable(Type value);
    Variable();
    template<typename T>
    T get();
    void* ptr();
};

#endif //VARIABLE_H

//Variable.cpp
template<typename Type>
Variable::Variable(Type value) {
    this->value = new Type(value);
}

Variable::Variable(){
  this->value = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
T Variable::get(){
    return static_cast<T>(this->value);
}

void* Variable::ptr() {
    return this->value;
}

//main.cpp
#include "Variable.h"

int main(){
  std::vector<Variable> conteinerOfDifferentTypes;
  conteinerOfDifferentTypes.push_back(new Variable<int>(15));
}
```